# Pandas Insert data into MySQL

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, mysql-python

I am trying to insert columns of data that I extracted from .csv file into MySQL using Pandas (Python).

Here is my code that I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@localhost/dbname')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():

df = pd.read_csv('File.csv', usercols=['ID', 'START_DATE'], skiprows=skip)
print(df)

df.to_sql(con=con, name='Table1', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

But, it does not mention about specific column names in Table1..

How do we express that?

Comment: What does the code you have in your question do? It is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `DataFrame.to_sql`... examples are in the docs. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql

Comment: @cricket_007 I added few lines (above). What I am trying to do is insert data from csv file ('ID' and 'START_DATE' column) into Table1.

Comment: sql.write_frame is not correct. Why are you trying that? Looks like you are entirely missing a SQLalchemy connection object, so get that working even before touching your csv file. You also don't need to read the table to a Dataframe before writing

Comment: @cricket_007  I modified the code little bit by upating MySQL db connection portion, and also deleted the sql.write_frame part. But I still am not understanding SQLalchemy connection object portion. Can you please give me some example? I Googled and looked for one, but I am not sure how to apply on my case where I take data from result of csv file and putting the data in MySQL.

Comment: `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://'+hostname, pool_recycle=3600)`, again, from the documentation. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html or http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#mysql but you don't need `pd.read_sql_table`

Comment: @cricket_007 I modified the code as above. So far, it is working fine as there is no error with code, and it prints data from csv file as expected. Now, how do I express so that data from csv file (df object) can be inserted into specific columns in MySQL table ('Table1')?

Comment: Whatever columns are already part of `df` during `df.to_sql` will be inserted into `name='Table1'` via `con=con`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your code should read like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('File.csv', usercols=['ID', 'START_DATE'], skiprows=skip)
print(df)

engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@localhost/dbname')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df.to_sql('Table1', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

But, regarding your question, unless I am mistaken in my understanding of Pandas, whatever columns `df` presently has, those are going to be written to the columns of the same name of the mysql table.

If you need different column names, you'll want to rename those in the DataFrame

Or use [the parameters, as mentioned](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql),

> **index** : boolean, default True
>   Write DataFrame index as a column.
>
> **index_label** : string or sequence, default None
>   Column label for index column(s). If None is given (default) and index is True, then the index names are used

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me try when my MySQL database is ready. I will get back to this if there is/are any issues.

Comment: Wait, why are you asking the question without a running mysql database to validate against?

Comment: It worked. Data got inserted beautifully.The database environment was not set up yesterday. Thank so much for all your help again.

Comment: Couple of syntax issues. Otherwise this is a great solution!

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=['ID', 'ColumnName'], skiprows=[1])

Comment: @unicatcode I copied `skiprows=skip` and `usercols` from the question

Answer (score 4):

This is what i did in my project

```
 import pandas as pd
 import sqlalchemy
 engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/pd_test')

 ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings2.csv', sep='\t', encoding='latin-1',
                  usecols=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'user_emb_id', 
 'movie_emb_id','rating'])

 ratings.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=1)
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: Install pymysql for this answer. Worked for me on Mac & venv.