# i have an error in using pandasql .my table is not getting identified

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

**error:**

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: aadhaar_data [SQL: 'select registrar,enrolment_agency from aadhaar_data limit 50;'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

**my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps
#how to use sql commands

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\Aadhaar_data.csv")
#we rename the columns
# by replacing spaces with underscores and setting all characters to 
lowercase, so the
# column names more closely resemble columns names one might find in a table
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_').lower(), inplace=True)
print(df)
q="""SELECT registrar,enrolment_agency FROM Aadhaar_data lIMIT 50;"""
#p="""SELECT * from aadhar_data;"""\
aadhaar_solution = ps.sqldf(q.lower(), locals())
print(aadhaar_solution)
aadhaar_solution=ps.execute_sql(q)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward - it means the table doesn't exist in the database. I can see some inconsistencies in the way you've typed it - for instance, your code there has the table as `Aadhaar_data` while in other places you've got it as `aadhar_data` and in another place as `aadhaar_data`. You've either mis-spelled the table somewhere or perhaps not inserted it at all - I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually insert the data to the table you're querying.

Comment: p="""SELECT * from aadhar_data;  this is a comment,everwhere else i have put Aadhaar_data only

Comment: Also,my file is named  Aadhaar_data.csv

Comment: Looking at your code I don't actually see a place where you explicitly store the data you've loaded from your CSV in the database. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288598/pandas-insert-data-into-mysql) it looks like you probably need to call `df.to_sql` somewhere first.

Comment: Can you suggest a good place from where i can learn these basics..i am new to data analytics and i really want to learn

Comment: @Sammy16 I mean a quick google search will get you to their 10-minute quickstart guide [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), which is probably as good a place to get started as anywhere. Google and reddit are your friends. StackOverflow is better for when you have a _specific_ programming issue that you need solved like: "I have this code, and I expect it to do A, but it does B instead -- why is that happening?".

Comment: I'd also be grateful if you marked my answer as accepted, since it is the technically correct answer for the problem you're facing.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'    ,could you pls help me resolve this

Comment: That needs to be a separate question. Also try googling - module not found is a really common error.